# Java repetitive pattern matching (2)

Tags: java, regex, matching, repeat

Consider the following regex:

```
(([^\|])*\|)*([^\|]*)
```

This matches **repetitive string patterns** of the type

```
("whatever except |" |) {0 to any times} ("whatever except |" |) {1 time}
```

So it should match the following String, which has 17 substrings (16 repeated, plus "  z" as the last one).

```
"abcd  | e | fg | hijk | lmnop | |   | qrs |   t| uv| w |||||x   y|  z"
```

Indeed, [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) verifies that the given regex does match the above string.

Now, I want to get each of the substrings (i.e., "abcd  |", "e |", "fg |", etc.), for which there is no prior knowledge about their number, length etc.

According to a similarly-titled [previous StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340364/java-repetitive-pattern-matching) and the documentation of the `Matcher` class `find()` method, I just need to do something like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); // regex is the above regex
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input); // input is the above string

while (matcher.find())
{
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

However, when I do this I just get 2 strings printed out: the last repeated substring ("x   y|") and a null value; definitely not the 16 substrings I expect.

A nice thing would also be to **check that a match has actually happened**, before running the `find()` loop, but I am not sure whether `matches()`, `groupCount() > 0`, or some other condition should be used, without doing twice the matching work, given that `find()` also does matching.

So, **questions**:

1. How can I get all the 16 repeated substrings?
2. How can I get the last substring?
3. How do I check that the string matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use the regular expression...

> 1) How can I get all the 16 repeated substrings?

See below. When cycling over for matches, you don't need everything to match, just the section you want. (I get 17 matches--is this correct?)

> 2) How can I get the last substring?

Switching the delim to the start of the regex and also allowing '^'.

> 3) How do I check that the string matched?

What qualifies for a non-match? Any string will match.

---

Here is a solution using regular expressions:

```java
String input = "abcd  | e | fg | hijk | lmnop | |   | qrs |   t| uv| w |||||x   y|  z";
int expectedSize = 17;
List<String> expected = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abcd  ", " e ", " fg ", " hijk ", " lmnop ", " ", "   ", " qrs ", "   t", " uv", " w ", "",
    "", "", "", "x   y", "  z"));

List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

// Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:\\||^)([^\\|]*)");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:_?\\||^)([^\\|]*?)(?=_?\\||$)"); // Edit: allows _| or | as delim

for (Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input); matcher.find();)
{
  matches.add(matcher.group(1));
}

for (int idx = 0, len = matches.size(); idx < len; idx++)
{
  System.out.format("[%-2d] \"%s\"%n", idx + 1, matches.get(idx));
}

assertSame(expectedSize, matches.size());
assertEquals(expected, matches);
```

Output

```
[1 ] "abcd  "
[2 ] " e "
[3 ] " fg "
[4 ] " hijk "
[5 ] " lmnop "
[6 ] " "
[7 ] "   "
[8 ] " qrs "
[9 ] "   t"
[10] " uv"
[11] " w "
[12] ""
[13] ""
[14] ""
[15] ""
[16] "x   y"
[17] "  z"
```

Comment: Many thanks for an excellent solution! May I ask for a slight expansion of that? The delimiter is sometimes prefixed by an underscore (_), giving _| between substrings, except for when the substring is empty, in which case it does not appear. So the situation could be something like "abcd _| e || fg _|||| hij". In other words, we have an "optional" underscore before | and I would like to leave that off when it appears (it does not appear within the substrings). I tried modifying your regular expression but what I came up with didn't work.

Comment: @PNS: So use `\G([^\|]+?)_?\||\G()\||\G([^\|]*)$` and get the group which is not null as your text. The first part accounts for non-empty data followed by a delimiter, the second part account for empty data followed by a delimiter, and the third part accounts for the data at the end.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you're confusing things. Whenever you use repetitions ('*', '+', etc.), you can't get all the instances matched. Using something like `((xxx)*)` you can get the whole string matched as `group(1)` and the last part matched as `group(2)`, nothing else.

Consider using `String.split` or better Guava's [Splitter](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html).

---

Ad 1. You can't. Use a simple pattern like

```
\G([^\|])*(\||$)
```

together with `find()` to get all the matches in sequence. Note the `\G` anchoring to a previous match.

---

Ad 2. How can I get the last substring?

As the last result `find` returns.

---

Ad 3. How do I check that the string matched?

After your last `find` check if `matcher.end() == input.length`. But with this pattern you don't need to check anything, as it always matches.

Comment: I am not sure how this works, but thanks. So, find() does go over all the matches!

Comment: My pattern is simpler than yours, so what part are you missing? `\G` makes sure your next match starts just when your previous ended. The first group means any number on non-pipes, the second group means either a pipe or the end. You may want to use `\Z' or '\z` instead of `$`.